# Proper syntax for a POST call to a URL

Tags: php, curl, post, cdata

I am having difficulty with the proper layout for this piece of code I have been talking with another IT support person and we are both at a bit of a loss

I am trying to utilize an API call and I am trying to come up with the proper syntax

I am using a PHP POST call and CURL along with an array of variable names and values for the most part it works

The problem is that a few variable names are not recognized and the other support person thought we needed to change things up a bit

The documentation states there may be a change we need to setup these variable ahead of time

the structure needs to be something like this CDATA block:

```
<profileFieldValues>
     <fieldValue id="_sys_firstname">
          <value>Jeff</value>
     </fieldValue>
     <fieldValue id="_sys_lastname">
          <value>Johnson</value>
     </fieldValue>
</profileFieldValues>
```

WE are using a structure like this

```
$fields = array(
        'restype' => '2',
        'username' => 'abc123',
         ...,
 )
```

So what would the profileFieldValues block of code be written to work in the  $fields array?

We were trying something like this but it was not correct

```
 'profileFieldValues'=>"fieldValue id[]=>('_sys_firstname=>'value'=>'Charlie','_sys_lastname=>'value'=>'Brown')",
```

we received an error with this:

The user profile field elements are not properly formatted

Comment: Is it a soap API? It may be easier to use the soapclient instead of curl if that's the case.

Comment: I looked at the documentation and it mentioned HTTP POST URL so that is where I started. I am new to working with these APIs and SOAP may be available but this method would easily drop into our current workings on our website. All other variables work just fine and the API functions as normal but their is a default setting that is used if two variable do not exist and these are the two and we can not use the default all 10 other variable and the method functions just fine so it is simply a syntax issue of some kind

Comment: I am trying Soap as well but I am also using an array there so the question still holds

Comment: This question of how to properly format a block of cdata fields and values into a single array of arrays of arrays etc. still needs to be answered  BUT I did resolve my particular problem and that was by adding the actual CDATA fields and value blocks nested properly directly into a single variable worked

Comment: this is the format that worked for me in my issue but it  does not answer the question however:  'ProfileFieldValues' =>'<ProfileFieldValues><FieldValue id="_sys_firstname"><Value>RED</Value></FieldValue><FieldValue id="_sys_lastname"><Value>BARON</Value></FieldValue></ProfileFieldValues>'